# Is it possible to download an old APK for my app from Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

Over the last few months, I've published several revisions to my app. Unfortunately, I didn't keep copies of all the old APKs, and now I'd like to test upgrade from the old versions to my new version. Is there any way to download Google's copy of my old versions? The Google Play developer console shows my old APKs, but without a download link. I tried "Real APK Leecher", but that doesn't let you choose the APK version you want to download. And I'm not able to even temporarily reactivate the old version in the Developer Console since it complains that it's of an earlier version.

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand that reactivate link, it never works.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

**THE ANSWER IS OUTDATED. NOW THIS IS POSSIBLE, CHECK [@tesla's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40037886/944070) AND [@olleh's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40759979/944070) ANSWERS.**

**FOR THE NEW 2020 GOOGLE PLAY CONSOLE, SEE ANSWER FROM [@IonicBurger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278387/is-it-possible-to-download-an-old-apk-for-my-app-from-google-play/63599659#63599659)**

No, unfortunately.

The Android Developer Console is a real disaster, everywhere you look there is something that needs to be fixed or improved, being this issue you mention one of them. Unfortunately for the  time being you're out of luck. Unless Google enables this, you cannot download old APKS's. I suppose you could recompile the old code, but I guess you don't have that either and that's why you are here :-)

Comment: I have it in source control, I was just trying to avoid getting Eclipse set up to rebuild those old versions.

Comment: Setup a jenkins server that will continuously build the apk for you for every check in. You can always retrieve previously built APK and do a quick test first, before wasting time setting up Eclipse to build a specific revision.

Comment: I have a similar issue, but in my case with one of my early apps I somehow lost the release APK's prior to v1.0.2 and didn't start using version control until v1.0.6. I don't need the APK's for compatibility testing or other development purposes, I want them more for historical purposes. I'm hopeful v2 of the Developer Console will allow downloading old APK's.

Comment: When is V2 of the developer console out?

Comment: @azgolfer: I am all for continuous integration, though a) in this case you need manual release build more than continuous integration and b) the normal Eclipse build can't be readily automated, so you need the alternate ant-based build (too).

Comment: It's pretty idiotic that Play store can't allow me to download a previous version of my own app.

Comment: If you want to pull only the latest you can download any apk extractor/downloader/share app from google play and use it to extract the apk file after installing our app to a device.

Comment: Recompiling is not an option, Different build tools produce different results. That why it is essential to get the old APK. This is really something in need of fixing, But google can be really stupid where it matters.

Comment: It is now possible in "Manage Releases"

Comment: please remove this answer as it is now obsolete

Comment: "everywhere you look there is something that needs to be fixed or improved". You can say that again! I've answered inumerous polls from Google about the Developer Console, giving the same suggestions over and over, and it feels like talking to a rock. One thing I've always ask Google is for a way to have a review mechanism for user reviews.

Comment: I added big bad comment in the answer, just to be sure no one will skip the other answers (like I almost did)

Comment: For people who are following this answer with the latest update: if you have multiple users signed into your Chrome, try opening up an incognito window and going to the developer console that way (after signing in with the master account). I was signed in with an account that apparently didn't have full access, so the download button wasn't available.

Comment: upvoted your answer as well for pointing towards other correct answers.

Answer (score 104):

Now it is possible. They added "Manage Releases" tab to Google Play Developer Console. From `Artifact Library` under the `Release Management` tab, you can download your app's APK.

You need to have the necessary permissions to see the download button next to your artifacts. If in doubt, try the root account.

Comment: I don't see an ability from the Manage Releases tab to change prod code to and older version.  I see older versions in the Atifact Library but I there are no actions available other than "download".  Still, you can download the old APK then i guess re-upload it to production??? lol

Comment: I have managed to download the APK, but not the corresponding .obb file

Comment: For people who are following this answer: if you have multiple users signed into your Chrome, try opening up an incognito window and going to the developer console that way (after signing in with the master account). I was signed in with an account that apparently didn't have full access, so the download button wasn't available.

Comment: Funny it only works from Chrome ;) on Firefox the download button wasn't available.

Comment: Go down to the entry by @kks21199 -- In April 2021 that is the right answer...you can skip the others.

Answer (score 54):

**Latest Update:**

Go to

> Developer Console => App releases => Production (Manage Production) => Release history => Select the version that you want => Click on Download button.

Your account should be granted with full permissions, otherwise the download button will be hidden.

**Original Answer**

Go to

> Developer Console => Manage Releases => Artifact Library = > Archived Artifacts

You get the option to download the previous releases.

**Update:**

Go to

> Developer Console => App releases => Artifact library => Check the version code/name you wanna download and click the download button at the right.

** Update: **

> Developer Console => App releases => Production (Manage Production) => Download arrow.

Comment: I went there. But couldn't see any option to download.

Comment: If you expand "Archived artifacts" section, you should see a whole list of APKs and in each row, there is a download button at the right.

Comment: Unfortunately, now there are no Archived artifacts, so downloading older version is impossible

Answer (score 49):

And yet again - this question needs a newer answer, with the latest update of the Google Play Console, 2020.

The steps to now follow are, in the console, go to:
App bundle explorer

[image]

On the top right corner, pick the artifact you want to download, then go to the Downloads tab. Scroll down to Assets, and look for the first entry in the table Original file. Click on the download icon to the right to download your APK or AAB file

[image]

Comment: This still works with Console as of Jan 31st, '21. 

Could they MAKE it any more button clicks? Wow.

Comment: I'll see what I can do to refer people to this, the only working answer today, April 2021. Sheesh!

Answer (score 6):

It's easy:

1- click on App bundle explorer, then select your desired version as shown:

[image]

2- Click on blue arrow in front of the version you want to download:
[image]

3- Select Download tab then click on download icon of apk:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

It’s **possible nowadays**.

**See screenshot below for clear picture.**

Google added "Manage" option inside "App Release" of Google Play Developer Console. From Manage tab, you can see Release History and download your app's APK.

***VISUAL EXPLANATION:: See 2 step process below.***

Step1: Go to Manage
[image: Step1: Go to Manage]
Step 2: Goto Release History Section -> Select version-> Download Apk

[image: Step 2: Goto Release History Section -> Select version-> Download Apk]

Answer (score 4):

I'll show you with screenshots, step by step:

1. Go to Production:
   [image: Production section]
2. Go to Releases tab and click on "View release details"
   [image: View release details]
3. In "App bundles" part, click on arrow:
   [image: App bundles part]
4. Into APK, click on "Explore Apk"
   [image: Explore Apk]
5. In Dowloads tab, click on "download" icon:
   [image]

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

**Screenshot of tesla's correct answer.  I had a little trouble finding the download icon:**

[image: where to click to download apk]

Comment: My screen looks identical to this, but I don't have a download button here.

Comment: you need full permission to account to get that download button visible

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to install old APK via link from Google Play Console. This way you install straight from Play Store rather than downloading the APK. This also works with app bundle which allows you to get optimized APK for your device.

1. In Google Play Console go to Development tools > Internal app sharing > Manage Testers
2. Add all testers you want to allow access to install old version of the app
3. If you upload app bundle you can go to Release management > Artifact library > Explore on the version you want.
4. The link shall be listed in Internal app sharing section. Here is the format if you cannot find the link (Be sure to replace to your applicationId and the versionCode for your app)
   https://play.google.com/apps/test/**applicationId**/**versionCode**
5. When you click the link on you device for the first time play store will say Internal app sharing is not enabled.
6. To enable Internal app sharing open Play Store > Settings
7. Scroll all the way down and keep clicking on Play Store version to enable developer mode
8. Once developer mode is enabled you will see Internal app sharing switch in the settings once enabled you will be able install your app from the link.

FYI: I have seen some version not working if they were not released to production track. I am able to install all my production tracks also any active artifacts listed in Artifact library in Google Play Console. This should be enough if you are trying to test upgrade scenarios.