# Android App Developer console: Backtrack to previous version?

Tags: android

Is it possible to backtrack to a previous version of a released Android app - if so will this version be replaced as part of the phones update service - or will I need to release a new version of the old app with a incremented version number?

Cheers
Paul

Answer (score 0):

You can reactivate previously uploaded versions. I don't know for how long they're saved or if they stay as long as you don't delete them.

Comment: cheers - I noticed that feature in the dev console - but wondered whther that then rolls out the old version as an update and removes the newer version?

Comment: Oh well, I stand corrected. There is, for the time being, no way to reactivate old versions. The developer panel will tell you that the version to be activated is of a lower version number than the previously active one. As far as I can tell from my own testing and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383321/android-apk-file-re-activate-older-apk-file-in-google-play-store) and [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278387/is-it-possible-to-download-an-old-apk-for-my-app-from-google-play) you'll have to compile a new old version. Sorry for misleading you.